# Excel automatically adds borders when changing cell value

Tags: excel, border, cell

I have been working on the same spreadsheet daily for over 4 months. As of this morning, whenever I change a cell value, excel adds a border line that extends from A to ZZZ. I have removed all formatting(there is no VBA coding in the workbook) from the sheet but no matter what if I change a value the border appears. As this book is something I report out of, the borders are killing me slowly. I have searched the internet looking for solutions but it appears I am the only one. Any advice would be appreciated, I've exhausted all my options.

Comment: Have you checked the cells for any conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes-there is no conditional formatting left.even if I open a new workbook it does the same.

Comment: I confirmed I am not the only one. It appears to be an issue with excel 2016. hopefully a fix will come soon

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a problem with the update KB4011050 for excel

Go to Control Panel > Programs > Programs & Features > Installed Updates
 look for the update for Office 2016 Excel KB4011050

Uninstall this update

[KB4011050](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4011050/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforexcel2016september12-2017)

You can also fix the issue by installing [KB4011165](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/4011165/september-12-2017-update-for-excel-2016-kb4011165)